# Data Science: Using Inferential Statistics to label train dataset

Tags: machine-learning, modeling, data-mining, inference, pandas

Lack of High Schools in remote areas is a problem for students in developing country. Students in some locations are better than that in other. So, I have to find those locations. Now, the main problem is defining "BETTER". I have made some rules that will define the profile of a location.

Right now, I am concerned with the good students. So, what I have done is- 1. Used some inferential statistics to and made some rules to come up with the conclusion that Location A,B,C,etc are the most potential locations where you can put the high schools because according to my rules these locations contain quality students.

I did all of the things above to label the data because I required to define "BETTER" and label the data so that I can now use machine learning to learn the factors which makes a location a potential location so that if I give a data point from test data to the model, it will instantly tell if the location is better or not.

Overview of the method: For each location, I have these 4 pieces of information:

- total_students_staying_for_high_school_education(A), -
- total_students_leaving_for_high_school_education_in_another_place(B), -
- mean_grade_point_of_students_of_type_B,
- ratio (calculated as B/A),

For the location whose ratio > 1

1. I calculated the chi-squared significance test to come up with a
   statistic which would tell me if students are leaving that place in
   significant amount than staying. I used ANOVA and then Tukey test to
   compare means_grade points and then find combinations of pairs of
   locations whose means vary and whose is greater than the others.
2. I then wrote a python program with a custom comparator that first
   compares if mean_grade of those points vary and returns the one with
   greater mean. If the means don't vary, the comparator return the
   location with the one whose chi-squared value is greater.

This is how, the whole process comes up with few suggestions of location and I call those locations: "BETTER".

What I am concerned about is-

1. How do I verify if my rules are valid? Or do I even need to verify it?
2. Most importantly, is mingling statistics with machine learning as described above an appropriate approach?Is there any major leakage in the method?
3. Can anyone suggest a more general method?